# How to filter spreadsheet for rows in which a column's value is unique?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of 100,000 rows which has two columns. I'd like to filter this table to get *only* the rows for which the value in the second column is unique. That is, if I have:

[image]

I would like to only end up with the rows where B = 1, 2 and 4.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column.  In that column place the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2)=1
```

If it is not unique it will return `FALSE`.

[image]

Then filter on the `True` in the helper column:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, because I have 100,000 rows, it crashes Excel, every time.

Comment: @imnui try this formula instead in C2: `=AND(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$B$1:B1,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(B2,B3:B$1040000,0)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner that's a fascinating construction, would you mind adding some explanation as to why that method is more resilient over large datasets?

Comment: @AlexM not sure it is, I was hoping the OP would come back and let us know if it worked or not.